# Nested list duplication ranking

Tags: python, list

Consider the following nested list in Python:

```py
[
    ['Val1', 1, 'X'],
    ['Val2', 1, 'X'],
    ['Val2', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val3', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val4', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val4', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val5', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val6', 3, 'Z'],
]
```

Where there is a duplicate at index 0. I want to obtain a new list from this one, with the duplicates removed, keeping the ones with the highest value at index 1. In the above example, the resulting list should look like so:

```py
[
    ['Val1', 1, 'X'],
    ['Val2', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val3', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val4', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val5', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val6', 3, 'Z'],
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [max(g, key=lambda i: i[1]) for k, g in groupby(data, lambda i: i[0])]
[['Val1', 1, 'X'],
 ['Val2', 2, 'Y'],
 ['Val3', 2, 'Y'],
 ['Val4', 3, 'Z'],
 ['Val5', 3, 'Z'],
 ['Val6', 3, 'Z']]
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I am looking for. For my education could you please break down this line of code and explain what it is doing?

Comment: @Cory correct me if I am wrong. here you are first grouping by the i[0] which will give the unique values for index 1 i.e Val1, Val2,Val3. And since you are using the max(g, key=lambda i: i[1]) you are making the program to group by via values (val1,val2,val3) that have the highest index 1

Comment: Update: I ran in to a problem where this method would not eject the dups unless it was sorted by index[0] first. For example if the input list had Val1,Val2,Val1 it would not throw out the dup Val1. Sorting the list first fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas

```
x = [['Val1', 1, 'X'],
    ['Val2', 1, 'X'],
    ['Val2', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val3', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val4', 2, 'Y'],
    ['Val4', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val5', 3, 'Z'],
    ['Val6', 3, 'Z']]

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(x).sort_values([0, 1]).drop_duplicates(subset=[0], keep='last').values.tolist()
```

Comment: what does the statement keep = 'last' and subset =[0] do. Aditionally, .values.tolist() converts it back to list i believe ?

Comment: first I sort by first and second column and then we pick the last one when there is duplicate (which corresponds to the max value of second column)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts

Step 1: Sort based on the second attribute.
Step 2: Sort based on the first attribute.
Since sorts are "stable" in python, the ordering on the sort in step 1 will be retained after step 2.

```
l = # list of similarly formatted lists
l = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(1))
l = sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Alternatively, write your own comparison key function. I think this should actually work because tuples are compared in order from left to right:

```
l = sorted(l, key=tuple)
```